# My PC no longer recognizes my android phone

Tags: windows, usb-debugging

My PC no longer recognizes my android phone..Whenever I connect my phone via usb cable to the pc , I get the "One of the USB devices attached to your computer has malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it" error..I tried with a different usb cable, unplugged the power supple, restarted pc but nothing helps.My phone still charges though.What I also did was I connected my other android phone using the same cable but it was recognized !.So what could be the problem?

PC: Windows 7 32 bit
Android: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo SM-N7505 5.1.1 with root

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the USB cable is not damaged. Or check the USB port on the phone, try cleaning it then retry connecting to the computer.

Comment: Like I said I connected the same cable to a different phone and it worked so it is not the cable

Comment: So the problem resides in the phone itself. The USB port is probably broken, some pins may not attached to the motherboard anymore or simply cleaning the port may solve the problem.

Comment: But how is it charging?

Comment: The problem is your driver for phone in windows got corrupted. That is why it's charging. To overcome this situation try to find driver for yourself.

Comment: Where is the driver?

Comment: Wait, it doesn't recognizes on ADB or you can't access media? Some time ago I had same error but everything worked fine it gave me error but device was recognized. However try reinstalling drivers for phone.

Comment: The problem may be the drivers as mentioned by Vivek Ji. Download Samsung USB drivers and install them. Open the Device Manager and post the screenshot

Comment: Samsung usb drivers are already installed

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling usb tethering mode in Settings>Connections>More Networks> Tethering & Hotspot>USB Tethering.
 If your pc detects a RIDNS device, it means that you are able to send/recieve data through USB connection
else
You can try plugging in another pc or laptop
Also find your device drivers online and reinstall them